Animated film seen in 80's with a female humanoid that wants to be human
I have searched the net long and hard to find the name of an animated film I saw in the late 80's or early 90's. No luck!
I think it is Japanese but could be wrong.
I am sure it begins with a package being delivered to a home of a young boy which is the female humanoid. May be wrong there. 
It may have been of some kind of car. I remember the film includes a car and car chase where the car drives on top of a bridge to escape. 
The film also includes a scene in a work camp prison and escape from it and the only other thing I remember is a scene where the female humanoid loves flowers (I think?) and a scene where she wants to love or falls in love but realises she is a robot? 
I think it ends with her being able to cry real tears? It is quite a sad ending. Once again I could be wrong. 
Could have been from the 1970's but probably 80's?

The term humanoid is more open-ended than you realize. Did you mean android?

Thanks, I never realised this but you are absolutely correct, have googled it. Thankfully another member found the film so all is good!
Cheers.

I was looking for it myself and even posted a question on Science Fiction and Fantasy about it. Now I found it — I am pretty sure it is Space Firebird 2772/Phoenix 2772. 
The scene with the package delivered is at the beginning, after the boy is raised by the machines until he is about 8, I guess. The robot is Olga. The end is relatively sad as he dies and she turns human, but he resurrects as a small baby. There is a work camp involved at some point. 
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenix_2772.

Yes, this is it!!!!
Thank you so much, I've been looking for this for over 10 years! It has literally bought tears to my eyes, I never thought I'd ever find it, this film is something that stayed with me for years and it is incredibly emotional having finally found it!
Thank you so much, I really appreciate it, I have searched everywhere for this but thought it was gone forever.
The soundtrack is amazing, it's on youtube and I'll be searching out the DVD or Blu-ray should one exist!
Amazing website and it's made my day!
Thanks again mate!

There are two possibilities I can think of, although I'm not sure that either is a perfect match:
1) For some reason, I am reminded of All-Purpose Cultural Cat Girl Nuku Nuku.
The main characters are a young boy (Ryu) and Nuku Nuku - an android shell implanted with the brain of a stray cat Ryu found, who gains a certain amount of intelligence from the process, but retains many of her feline instincts.  Hilarity ensues.
The OVA from 1991 opens with Ryu's father stealing the android shell from his ex-wife's tech company, having it in the back of his car, and driving like a maniac to escape attack helicopters sent to catch him in what could certainly be called a car chase, of sorts.  He does drive over a bridge at one point during the scene, although he doesn't technically escape then.
I don't remember any prison camp or flowers, but the show did have its share of wacky antics and heartfelt moments.  Nuku Nuku certainly cares for Ryu, although it's not romantic love, more like sisterly love.  She's also perfectly well aware of her own origin and the fact that she's a robot.
The ending wasn't sad at all, but Nuku Nuku was certainly capable of emotion and may have cried at points.  I've only seen the original OVA, but there was at least one TV series reboot in 1998, and possibly a second since.  Perhaps one of those has the missing scenes and a similar opening?
2) El Hazard: The Magnificent World
Another OVA series from the 90's.  It doesn't start with a car chase or a package being delivered, although it certainly does have an android girl who arrives near the beginning.  The fact that she's a robot was not a secret to her, but it wasn't revealed to us as viewers until part-way through.  She later falls in love and there's a tear-jerker of an ending, for sure.
Between the two, I'm thinking Nuku Nuku has a better chance of being right.
